# wget download files in parallel and rename

Tags: bash, unix

I have a text file with two columns: the first column is the name to be saved as, and the second column is the url address to the resource.

```
10000899567110806314.jpg 'http://lifestyle.inquirer.net/files/2018/07/t0724cheekee-marcopolo_1-e1532358505274-620x298.jpg'
10001149035013559957.jpg 'https://www.politico.eu/wp-content/uploads/2018/07/GettyImages-1004567890.jpg'
10001268622353586394.jpg 'http://www.channelnewsasia.com/image/10549912/16x9/991/529/a7afd249388308118058689b0060a978/Zv/tour-de-france-5.jpg'
10001360495981714191.jpg 'https://media.breitbart.com/media/2018/07/Dan-Coats.jpg'
```

The file contains thousands of lines, so I wanted a quick way to download and rename these images.

I read multiple posts on SO and came up with this solution:

```
cat list.txt  | xargs -n 1 -P 4 -d '\n' wget -O
```

Which uses `xargs` to download in parallel. I want to use `wget` with `-O` option to rename the downloaded file. When I run a single `wget` command, this works well. Example:

```
wget -O 10000899567110806314.jpg 'http://lifestyle.inquirer.net/files/2018/07/t0724cheekee-marcopolo_1-e1532358505274-620x298.jpg'
```

but when running the command with xargs to download in parallel, I get this error:

```
Try `wget --help' for more options.
wget: missing URL
Usage: wget [OPTION]... [URL]...
```

If I generate a file with just (single col) newline delimited urls and run the following command, it works great.

```
cat list.txt  | xargs -n 1 -P 4 -d '\n' wget
```

But, I don't want to download the files first and then do the rename operation.

Comment: Wouldn't `xargs < list.txt -P 4 -L 1 wget -O` be enough?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The error you are getting is because you are only passing one argument `-n 1` to make it work you need to pass the 2 arguments, try this:

```
cat list.txt | xargs -n 2 -P 4 wget -O
```

To use the full line as an argument as @PesaThe suggested you could use option `-L 1`, for example:

```
xargs < list.txt -P 4 -L 1 wget -O
```

From the man:

```
 -L number
     Call utility for every number non-empty lines read. 
     A line ending with a space continues to the next non-empty line. 
     If EOF is reached and fewer lines have been read than number then utility 
     will be called with the available lines.  The -L and -n options are
     mutually-exclusive; the last one given will be used.
```