# parallel wget download url list and rename

Tags: bash, unix

Based on the accepted answer for question [wget download files in parallel and rename](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51582392/wget-download-files-in-parallel-and-rename)

`cat list.txt | xargs -n 2 -P 4 wget -O`

What is the GNU Parallel version of the command?

I have tried `cat list.txt | parallel -N2 -j 20 --gnu "wget {2} -O {1} --no-check-certificate"` but not success

Answer (score 0):

If:

```
cat list.txt | xargs -n 2 -P 4 wget -O
```

works. Then the GNU Parallel version is:

```
cat list.txt | parallel -n 2 -P 4 wget -O
```

GNU Parallel is designed to be able to be a drop-in replacement for most `xargs` situations.